# Warning только для своего кода?

Tags: c++

Можно ли как-то указать, чтобы не включался для всего проекта warning?

Когда я выставил уровень warning максимальный, то полетели ошибки сторонних библиотек и, похоже, самой visual, буста. Их очень много. 
В Интернете информации не нашел.

Answer (score 2):

Herb Sutter рекомендует компилироваться с максимальным уровнем warning'ов, и добиваться кода, их не выдающего. А для выборочного отключения warning'ов в сторонних библиотеках подключать их не напрямую, а через свой промежуточный header, в котором отключить warning'и именно для подключаемых библиотек. То есть в Вашем случае надо создать один или несколько header'ов вида:

externals.h

```
#pragma warning (push)
#pragma warning(disable:4700)
#include "externlib.h"
#pragma warning (pop)
```

Описание прагм есть, например, [тут:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/2c8f766e.aspx)